Rocky 9 - CMake - the dkms.conf file does not exist error when trying to install OCIO
I'm trying to install OCIO on Rocky 9 (please bear in mind that I am absolutely new to Linux and am doing this for work). I started by updating all of Rocky 9's dependencies, then I installed the GCC Compiler (11.4.1) and then CMake (3.26.5). Then I ran the following command:
sudo $ cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/software/ocio /source/ocio
where software/ocio is the final install directory and /source/ocio is the location of the OCIO source code (where the main CMakeLists.txt file is located). Running this command results in the following error:
[user.name@COMPUTERNAME123 ociobuild]$ sudo cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/user.name/software/ocio /usr/src/usb-vhci-1.15.6
CMake Error: File /usr/src/usb-vhci-1.15.6/dkms.conf.in does not exist.
Cmake Error at CMakeLists.txt:22 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

A screenshot of the terminal showing the dkms.conf file error
As I am a beginner to Linux in general, I'm not sure what to do at this point or what any of it really means. But I would like to fix this if possible.
Looking online I found that others had been experiencing similar issues. Most of the threads I found recommended that I try and use the following script:
for i in /var/lib/dkms/*/[^k]*/source; do [ -e "$i" ] || echo "$i";done
in order to locate the "offending module". However when I printed this in the terminal nothing occurred. I was able to find two dkms.config files manually, there were in /usr/src/nvidia-560.35.03 and usr/src/usb-vhci-1.15.6 respectively. However I don't know what to do with that information.

Smells like you choose wrong directory as a source one. What do you mean by "ocio" project? My google finds nothing with that name.

Maybe OpenColorIO? Regardless, as @Tsyvarev pointed out, OP isn't running cmake on "OCIO", they're running it on "usb-vhci" which aparently is missing an input file.
